# this.parse(attributes); in backbone's model sourcecode

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js

I was just wondering some OO while reading backbone's source.
http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html (search for "this.parse(attributes);")

```
  Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
var defaults;
attributes || (attributes = {});
console.log('attributes : ', attributes);
if (options && options.parse) {
  //LOOK HERE
  attributes = this.parse(attributes);
}
if (defaults = getValue(this, 'defaults')) {
  attributes = _.extend({}, defaults, attributes);
}
if (options && options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
this.attributes = {};
this._escapedAttributes = {};
this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
if (!this.set(attributes, {silent: true})) {
  throw new Error("Can't create an invalid model");
}
delete this._changed;
this._previousAttributes = _.clone(this.attributes);
this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
```

};

how does it come that parse can be used there in the prototype ? 
the method is defined later in _.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, Backbone.Events, {

Comment: Expressions don't actually get evaluated until they are run -- anything inside the function doesn't get evaluated when it's first defined, only when it's run.  Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/tUyhL/2/

Comment: thanks everybody, that makes it clear. Anyway, it feels to me that this method is only meant to be overriden, since it is simply returning its param :
parse: function(resp, xhr) { return resp; },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you see in function is going to be executed when someone is doing

```
new Backbone.Model
```

By that time, `Backbone.Model.prototype` will be defined as well. So property lookup will find `parse` method on `this.constructor.prototype` (where `this` will be pointing at just created instance of `Backbone.Model`).

Answer (score 2):

Even though the method is added to the prototype later on in the source code, it will still be available (with the rest of the prototype) when a `Backbone.Model` is actually created from the constructor function.